# onAlarm fired receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I want to create a broadcast receiver that will get notified when an alarm is started.
For example I set the alarm to 10 am and I go to sleep, then when the alarm is fired I want to have an receiver that will be notified.

Is it possible to do this ?, is there any intent that is fired on alarm start ?

Answer (score 1):

For setting alarm use [Alarm-manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class. You can set alarm using pending intent and using calendar you can set the time. Check the following code, in this AlarmReceiever is broadcast receiver which receives intent from pending intent at specific time that you can set in set method as second parameter .

```
  Intent alaram=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(FirstActivity.this, 0, alaram,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent); 
    //cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

cant you use pendingIntent too!! just saying

Comment: well I would use anything that will notify my broadcast receiver when the alarm is fired

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no standart alarm used by alarm applications.  So either you have to look up used alarm in your logs  and use it ( this will be alarm application dependent,  and
surely not portable ) or just use alarm manager and schedule your own alarm